# why do i recieve undefined from post request express

Tags: javascript, express

router for post action

```
router.post('/mainform', (req, res)=>{
 console.log(req.body.inp)
})
```

code, that makes request width fetch from a client

```
const form = document.querySelector('.toHandle')

const handleForm = (e)=>{
 e.preventDefault()
 const inp = e.target.inp.value
 fetch('/api/mainform', {
     method: 'POST',
     body: inp,
 })  
}



form.addEventListener('submit', handleForm)
```

i'm triyng to console.log req data and get undefined, just cant figure out why

Comment: you probably need a [`bodyParser` middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html). But its hard to say as we can only see a segment of your code.

Comment: i have it required and used

Comment: A closer look reveals that you just need to log `req.body` without `inp`. Do you see anything at all under `req.body`?

Comment: just an empty object

Comment: Maybe try adding  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },

Comment: just figured out, that i sholud add headers and pass json to body

Comment: `        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', },
         body: JSON.stringify({
            data: inp,
          })`